# How to split a output string at new-line in bash

Tags: linux, bash, dns, terminal, splitter

I am writing a little command which uses nslookup to just get the IP address of a domain name.

Here is what I have done:

```
nslookup scanme.nmap.org | grep -i "Address"  | awk '{print $2}'
```

Output:

```
127.0.0.53#53
45.33.32.156
2600:3c01::f03c:91ff:fe18:bb2f
```

Now from the above I just want to get the second line, i.e ***45.33.32.156***. I am relatively new to Ubuntu and Linux in general so please help me out even if it might be really simple (I am really struggling!!). Thanks in advance. ;-)

Comment: Do you always want only the second line from the top?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To get the second line, use `sed -n '2 p'`:

```
$ printf "127.0.0.53#53\n45.33.32.156\n2600:3c01::f03c:91ff:fe18:bb2f" | sed -n '2 p'
45.33.32.156
```

Comment: Thanks mate, that really worked. Much appreciated help. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Since you already use awk to get the second column you can also tell
it to only process the 2nd record:

```
$ nslookup scanme.nmap.org | grep -i "Address"  | awk 'NR==2 {print $2}'
45.33.32.156
```